# .class file not being created in Sublime Text: Java

Tags: java, sublimetext3, .class-file

I am starting to learn Java and decided to use sublime text. I prepared a build system that would allow me to both compile and run the program. When I created my first file, it gave an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Helloworld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Helloworld
```

My code:

```
public class Helloworld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Helloworld")
    }
}
```

The name of this file is Helloworld.java. I noticed one thing that the directory in which I saved this file didn't have the main class file. I am confused. Please help.

Build system code:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "java $file_base_name"
}
```

Comment: "shell_cmd": "javac $file_base_name" u should write javac rather than java

Answer (score 4):

`javac $file_base_name` (note the c) will **compile** your source file; `java com.foo.YourClass` will run it - note that the `java` command does *not* take a filename; it takes a class name.

More generally once you introduce packages and dependencies these scripts become impossible. Instead, use a build system and then if you still insist on using SublimeText (the vast majority of java programmers use IDEs such as Eclipse or IntelliJ), you can put `mvn compile` or `mvn run` in your compile/run scripts.